# Core Data lack of third degree object results in second-degree object not saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have the following data model:

```
ObjectA <->> ObjectB <->> ObjectC
```

In other words, each `ObjectA` has many `ObjectB`, which in turn has many `ObjectC`.

The relationships are all set up with correct inverses (as far as I can tell).

Saving the `managedObjectContext` results in everything getting saved correctly, but only as long as the data model is "complete" (i.e., `ObjectA` actually has `ObjectB` entities, which has `ObjectC` entities).

However, if `ObjectB` does not have any `ObjectC` (which is sometimes the case), `ObjectB` does not get saved.

Are there any obvious culprits for this behavior? I don't even know where to start looking.

The classes for the objects are set up as follows:

`ObjectB` has an `.objectA` property

`ObjectC` has an `.objectB` property

Both property names have the same name as the relation.

I've also tried adding NSSet properties (with the same name as the inverse relation) with no difference in behavior.

Comment: Can you post the entity diagram please

Comment: I cannot see why that should happen. Saving a context saves all objects created (or modified) in the context, whether they have relationships or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments -- it's solved now. This was due to an error external to Core Data. Before either updating or inserting new objects, I checked an ID column. It turns out the ID:s in this column (supplied by an external service) were not unique. This resulted in objects getting re-assigned to other parents.